# Yii2 file Downloading Error

Tags: php, yii2, download

When i call this function first time then file downloaded but after refresh the page it show me some not understanding  character on my browser screen

```
    // Controller Code

     public function actionDownload($id)
       {
                $model = $this->findModel($id);
                $file ='../frontend/uploads/users/'.$model->image;

                if(file_exists($file))
                {
                 return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
                 exit;
                }

    //Button Code
[
             'attribute'=>'resume',
             'label'=>'Resume',
             'format'=>'raw',
             'value'=>function($data)
             {
                   if($data->resume != null)
                   {
//                      $url = Yii::$app->params['application_base'].'admin/user/download/'.$data->id;
                      return Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=> $data->id]);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      return 'NA';
                   }
             },

            ],
```

Comment: Never call exit in a Yii app! `Yii::$app->end()`. Might even be the reason for the weird behavior as it does the response sending in there if needed.

Comment: how to remove pjax erro as i debug this it show me that second time pjax is calling and it show error

Comment: You might want to refer to [the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html). It tells you how to do that in the initial description.

Answer (score 1):

Try to omit a `pjax` amd use

```
return Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=> $data->id, 'data-pjax' => 0]);
```

instead of

```
return Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=> $data->id]);
```

Comment: return Html::a('Download', ['download','id'=> $data->id], ['data-pjax' => '0']); You have to provide 'data-pjax' => '0' as an option.